# Understanding the behavior of Python's set

Tags: python, set

The documentation for the built-in type `set` says:

```
class set([iterable])
```

> Return a new set or frozenset object
>   whose elements are taken from
>   iterable. The elements of a set must
>   be hashable.

That is all right but why does this work:

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> s = set(l)
>>> s
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

And this doesn't:

```
 >>> s.add([10])

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
        s.add([10])
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Both are lists. Is some *magic* happening during the initialization?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you initialize a set, you provide a list of values that must *each* be hashable.

```
s = set()
s.add([10])
```

is the same as

```
s = set([[10]])
```

which throws the same error that you're seeing right now.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [13]: (2).__hash__
Out[13]: <method-wrapper '__hash__' of int object at 0x9f61d84>

In [14]: ([2]).__hash__ # nothing.
```

The thing is that `set` needs its items to be hashable, i.e. implement the `__hash__` magic method (this is used for ordering in the tree as far as I know). `list` does *not* implement that magic method, hence it cannot be added in a set.

Comment: I am aware I can do that. That is not the question. Read the last line please.

Comment: I see, but the `list` is not hashable. So how does it work then?

Comment: @AA it does not work. `set([1,2])` is the equivalent of `x = set(); x.add(1); x.add(2)`

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
s.add([10])
```

You are trying to add a list to the set, rather than the elements of the list.  If you want ot add the elements of the list, use the update method.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the constructor being something like:

```
class Set:
    def __init__(self,l):
        for elem in l:
            self.add(elem)
```

Nothing too interesting to be concerned about why it takes lists but on the other hand `add(element)` does not.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves according to the documentation: `set.add()` adds a single element (and since you give it a list, it complains it is unhashable - since lists are no good as hash keys). If you want to add a list of elements, use `set.update()`. Example:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> s.add(5)
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3, 5])
>>> s.update([8])
>>> s
set([8, 1, 2, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

s.add([10]) works as documented. An exception is raised because [10] is not hashable.

There is no magic happening during initialisation.

set([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) has the same effect as set(range(10)) and set(xrange(10)) and set(foo()) where

```
def foo():
    for i in (9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0):
        yield i
```

In other words, the arg to set is an *iterable*, and each of the values obtained from the iterable must be hashable.